# having problem while resizing image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, resize, intervention

I am getting error while resizing image in laravel using Intervention Image

Link of the Library: http://image.intervention.io/

```
$featured_image = $request->file('featured_image');
$tmpFilePath = public_path('upload/properties/'); //Path to the Folder
$name = 'property_'.time().'.'.$featured_image->extension();
$featured_image->move($tmpFilePath, $name);

//Image resizing 
$image_original_path = $tmpFilePath.$name;
$image_resize = Image::make($image_original_path);              
$image_resize->resize(383,251);
$resize = public_path($tmpFilePath).'thumb_'.$name;            
$image_resize->save($resize);
```

and getting below error

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException
Can't write image data to path 
(/var/www/html/public/var/www/html/public/upload/properties/thumb_property_1630666129.jpeg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `public_path()` *twice* in your code, which leads to the invalid path `var/www/html/public/var/www/html/public/...`.
Change

```
$resize = public_path($tmpFilePath).'thumb_'.$name;
```

to

```
$resize = $tmpFilePath.'thumb_'.$name;
```